# Are there libraries for other languages that can parse json references like dojox.json.ref does?

Tags: json

See http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/17/json-referencing-in-dojo/ for how it's used in dojo. I'm looking for libraries that can do the same thing for C++, Java, Python, PHP, or any other language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON.Net (http://json.codeplex.com/) library can do this for C#.  I do not know about other languages.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the syntax is slightly different ("id" vs "$id"), but it does the same thing. Details at http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/PreserveObjectReferences.html